Проблема с выводом кириллицы при вводе символов с клавиатуры
Тут такая проблема, что все слова на кириллице выводятся нормально, кодировку utf-8 и не только делал, все слова выводятся нормально, НО именно при вводе с клавиатуры вместо слов знаки вопроса, подскажите, что делать?

Возможный дубликат вопроса: C++ curl получить utf-8 в кирилице

вот еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0
